# Windows 8.1 c# xaml - change background colour of stackpanel onBind

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8.1

I am binding `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` to a gridview, but I need to change the background colour of a stackpanel within that `GridView.ItemTemplate` when a value exists in `ObservableCollection<MyOtherClass>`.

I have reviewed several tutorials [(example)](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html) and question on this subject but none have helped. I have also tried binding the data to the gridview then looping through that gridview using `gv.Items` and access the stackpanel that way, obviously I have failed.

What is the best way to achieve my desired outcome?

```
<GridView x:Name="gv" Margin="30,0,0,0" ItemClick="gv_ItemClick"  Holding="itemGridView_Holding" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridViewItem >
                <!--<Grid>-->
                   <StackPanel x:Name="spJobDisplay" Width="350" Background="White" >                                
                       <Image Source="{Binding Images[0].Source}" />
                       <StackPanel>
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedSupplier.SupplierName}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>   
                       </StackPanel>
                   </StackPanel>
                <!--</Grid>-->
            </GridViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

As you can see above I have set `spJobDisplay` stackPanel to white. It is that which I would like to to changed based on values in `ObservableCollection<MyOtherClass>`